# how to combine "Choose folder command" with "adding folder items" function with Applescript

Tags: applescript, directory

I'm using a folder action to create a "hot" folder, which immediately duplicates the files placed in this folder to a specific backup folder.

This is the script I'm using as folder action and it works fine:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
   tell application "Finder" to duplicate these_items to folder 
   ("Macintosh HD:Users:photograper:Desktop:Target:")
end adding folder items to
```

But I want to run this folder action like a normal applescript and trigger the "adding folder items" function  with a "Choose folder" command. So I can manually point a specific source and target folder and get the script running.

I tried this, but no result:

```
set this_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select source folder:" 
with multiple selections allowed
set target_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select backup folder:"


on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
   tell application "Finder" to duplicate these_items to target_folder
end adding folder items to
```

Any suggestions how to combine the two parts of scripting together so they can interact?

Comment: You might have better chances at https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you use folder action, dropping files on the folder will run the part of code between 'on adding folder...' and 'end adding folder...'. Therefore, if you want to choose destination folder, it must be between these 2 statements. Please note that files added are already in variable these_items, so no need to ask them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pbell. I wan't to use the folder action. When a file is dropped on the folder I wan't it to duplicate to a destination folder immidiatly, That is what I wan't.  I tried to put the "Choose folder" command for setting the dest. folder inside the 2 statements, but then every time a file is dropped it will trigger the "choose window". Is there a way to set the destination folder once? which is used by every file dropped on the source folder?

Comment: @pbell, this is what I tried:

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
   set target_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select backup folder:"
   tell application "Finder" to duplicate these_items to target_folder 
end adding folder items to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example bellow the destination folder is set to a folder "Target" on your desktop. You may adjust it to your need.

Warning: this example does not manage the case when Target folder does not exists !

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items

    set DestFolder to ((path to desktop folder) as string) & "Target:"
    tell application "Finder" to duplicate these_items to folder DestFolder

end adding folder items to
```

Each time you will drop files in folder link to that script, the files will be duplicated to Target.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the handler and change the variable "these_items" for "this_folder", like so:

```
set this_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select source folder:" with multiple selections allowed
set target_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select backup folder:"

tell application "Finder" to duplicate this_folder to target_folder
```

Then run the script as a normal script, and it will copy the folder entirely to your destination.

If, on the other hand, you just want the items to be copied, you could do this variation:

```
set this_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select source folder:" with multiple selections allowed
set target_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select backup folder:"

tell application "Finder"
    set these_items to list folder of this_folder without invisibles
    repeat with i from 1 to count of these_items
        set ItemX to item i of these_items
        set ItemX to (this_folder & ItemX as string) as alias
        duplicate ItemX to target_folder
    end repeat
end tell
```

Either way, you would end up with a duplicate.